# Binding multiple properties through converter to one value

Tags: android, binding, xamarin, converters, mvvmcross

I'm using MvvmCross 4 and trying to bind to the backgroundColor of `ListView` elements in axml. The problem now is that the color depends on 2 properties in my model: bool `IsSpecialCategory` and bool `IsNsfw` - each combination should get another color.

In iOS, using the fluent syntax, it was no problem to use the whole model in the converter, but is this possible in Android using axml? The easiest solution would be to feed the converter with the whole model in the item layouts, not just a property:

```
<LinearLayout [...]
local:MvxBind="backgroundColor ItemBackgroundColorConverter(theWholeModelNotJustAProperty)">
```

Comment: local:MvxBind="BackgroundColor CellChannelItemBackgroundColorConverter()"

...is enough and you get the whole model. Sometimes it's really easy ;)

Answer (score 3):

No need to pass the entire viewmodel to the converter when you can pass an extra parameter. :)

```
local:MvxBind="BackgroundColor PlayerBackgroundColor(RowItem.RowId, PlayerListType)
```

and converter:

```
public class PlayerBackgroundColorValueConverter : MvxColorValueConverter
{
    protected override MvxColor Convert(object value, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var playerListType = (PlayerListType)parameter;

        if (parameter != null && playerListType == PlayerListType.AllPlayers)
            return BusinessConstants.Top10BGColor;

        if ((int)value <= 10)
            return BusinessConstants.Top10BGColor;
        else
            return BusinessConstants.MyPlayersBGColor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible syntaxes for binding the entire context. One is omitting the property and the other is using a period:

```
local:MvxBind="backgroundColor ItemBackgroundColorConverter(.)"
local:MvxBind="backgroundColor ItemBackgroundColorConverter()"
```

Note that this works for bindings without converters as well